# Proving $e^{x^2}+x \geq e^x$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:
$$e^{x^2}+x\geq e^x$$
I can prove it for $x<0$ and for $x>1$, but I'm having trouble with $x\in[0,1]$.
I've tried to integrate both sides
$$\int_0^1(e^{x^2}+x) dx\geq \int_0^1e^x dx\iff\int_0^1e^{x^2} dx\geq e-\frac{3}{2}$$
but I can't integrate $\int_0^1e^{x^2}dx$.
I feel like I'm missing some other simpler ways. Could someone help?

Comment: Note: $e^{x^2}$ doesn't have an elementary integral, so there's no hope of writing down a formula for that antiderivative. Incidentally, that particular antiderivative (up to a scalar) is important enough that it has a name: the [*imaginary error function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function).

Comment: Try substituting Taylor series; use the fact that $x^p > x^q$ for $p < q$ for $x \in (0,1).$

Comment: Do you know how to use the Mean Value Theorem to establish inequalities like this?

Comment: @WangYeFei In that link, cardinal's proof for $x \ge 0$ is very nice. For $x < 0$, alternative proof: Using the well-known $\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u$, we have $\mathrm{e}^{x^2} \ge 1 + x^2$ and $\mathrm{e}^x = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{-x}} \le \frac{1}{1 - x}$. Thus, we have $\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} \ge 1 + x^2 + x - \frac{1}{1 - x} = \frac{-x^3}{1 - x} \ge 0$.

Comment: A proof using Maclaurin series: For $x\in [0, 1]$, we have $\mathrm{e}^x = 1 + x + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} \le 1 + x + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{x^2}{k!} = 1 + x + x^2\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} - 2\right) = 1 + x + x^2(\mathrm{e} - 2)$. Also, $\mathrm{e}^{x^2} \ge 1 + x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the Maclaurin series.

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \ldots $$

$$ e^{x^2} = 1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2!} + \frac{x^6}{3!} + \ldots $$

So,

$$ e^x - e^{x^2} = x - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} - \left( \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{4!} \right) x^4 + \ldots $$

which is an alternating series of decreasing terms if $x \in [0,1],$ and since the first term is $x$ and the next term is non-positive, it follows that $ e^x - e^{x^2} \leq x\ \forall x \in [0,1].$

Comment: Admittedly this is not a "clever" answer though, but I didn't see a clever answer.

Comment: What is wrong with my answer?

Comment: @Bruno "Take a look at the graph" is *not* a mathematical proof.

Comment: Why is it not ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/sIlNIVXpIns

Comment: Feel free to ask that as another question/ I am not answering that now.

Comment: Ah. There *is* a clever answer in the linked duplicate...